# Adding labels to the next line of a BoxLayout

Tags: java, swing, oop, layout

I have a box layout that has a JLabel and a button next to it, as such:

```
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();

    panel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(panel,BoxLayout.X_AXIS));
    panel.add(new JLabel("Reference  "));
    panel.add(new JButton("HI"));

    frame.add(panel);
    frame.setSize(500,300);
    frame.setVisible(true);
```

This correctly presents a label called reference and a button right next to it. But if I want to present the same thing right below it (a new label, and another button), how would I do that?

Because simply creating another panel, and emulating what I did before, doesn't seem to work.

I.e

```
JPanel newPanel = new JPanel();
newPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(panel,BoxLayout.X_AXIS));
```

Or using HTML in a new label like

```
JLabel s = new JLabel("<html> <br>newLaberl </html>");
```

adding this to the panel still would print it on the same line, after the button, not the next, any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just have to set the layout of the JFrame get it working the way you said.
I used your example setting the frame layout to use a [GridLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/GridLayout.html)

```
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    JPanel panel2 = new JPanel();

    frame.setLayout(new GridLayout(2,1));
    panel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(panel,BoxLayout.X_AXIS));
    panel.add(new JLabel("Reference  "));
    panel.add(new JButton("HI"));

    panel2.setLayout(new BoxLayout(panel2,BoxLayout.X_AXIS));
    panel2.add(new JLabel("Reference2  "));
    panel2.add(new JButton("HI2"));

    frame.add(panel);
    frame.add(panel2);
    frame.setSize(500,300);
    frame.setVisible(true);
```

Answer (score 1):

boxlayout isn't maybe the best layout for such thing, i suggest you to go to

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/layoutlist.html

and take a look on the various layout and tutorial documented on Oracle's docs website.

this one could be usefull for your application 
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html